# Home node missing after Publish in Sitecore 8.0

Tags: sitecore, publish, sitecore8

Our business users were publishing few items. But unfortunately now Home node is missing from web database. We have 1 CM server and 2 CD server. Both cd server point to same web database.

Comment: when you click on content tree on master database, do you have any warning? like "If you publish now, the selected version will not be visible on the Web site because it is not in the final workflow step." or "This item will never be published because its "Publishable" option is disabled.
"

Comment: As @SitecoreClimber said it seems the item has publish restrictions. You can check it by clicking on the publish tab then on Change button

Comment: @SitecoreClimber there is no warning in master db Home node.

Comment: @Hishaam On clicking Change button I see version list with dates

Comment: @Shadab, please check my answer below. Thanks

Comment: Other items can you publish ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if there are any restrictions. Please check the following:

Go to the Publish tab then click on the Change button. The checkbox should be checked as shown below:

[image]

On the Item tab of the Popup, the Publishable Checkbox should be checked:

[image]

Finally, on the Targets Tab, none of the checkboxes should be checked.

[image]

Note that you can have different publishing targets and you can use this options to publish the item to a specific target.

Comment: publishable checkbox is checked in both tabs. In targets tab we have our web database checked as publishing target

Comment: So, the item will only be published to your web database. Does your CM and CD use the same database? Try to untick both and publish the item again to see if this fix the issue.

Comment: yes CM and CD use same web database. will untick and publishing Home node will restore it?

Comment: Yes, this should fix your issue. Since you are using the same database, it will overwrite your changes as publishing does not publish to all your targets at the same time